# Driftnet not picking any images from the target

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

I'm trying to learn ethical hacking and I'm starting with ARP SPOOFING. I used `driftnet` but seems I can't get the images on my target. I'm running Kali Linux on VirtualBox and my target is my Windows machine. I'm connected to the same network. Can someone give me a clue why I can't get the images?

Details:

- Router: `192.168.1.1`
- Target: `192.168.1.5`
- My IP:  `192.168.1.7`
- VM Connection type: `Bridged`
- Interface: `eth0`

[image: Kali Commands]

Windows URL I am browsing on Google.

[image]

Comment: Google Images is probably using HTTPS, meaning the traffic is encrypted and an MitM attacker cannot see it. Have you tried a website that does not use HTTPS?

Comment: Yes i tried it on http but no luck it's still cant get the images.

Comment: What website did you try? If you open Wireshark, can you see any of the victim's traffic? Also, does that version of `arpspoof` support the `-r` flag?

Comment: http://markinternational.info/ here's the site. Yes it is support `-r` flag sir.

Comment: Can you capture *any* traffic from the target? Are you trying to capture the traffic of the *host* machine from the *VM*?

Comment: Be aware that you are not censoring your MAC address there, like at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can only browse Google over `https` only and not `http`.Even if you force http, the response for that request will be a redirect to `https`.Along with the `arpspoof`, you will have to use a tool which will be a middle man doing the `ssl` handshake with the target's browser and Google. `MITMproxy` works great.There is still a catch though, the target's browser will flag the connection to be insecure, because `MITMproxy` will be using its own selfsigned certificate for handshake.Beacuse your other end  is Google, target won't be able to add an exception in the browser and continue browsing because `HSTS` is set.To force the browsing, you will have to add MITMproxy's cert to the trustable root certificates manually in the browser.

[Mitmproxy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mitmproxy.org/&ved=2ahUKEwi1q9bv8OPZAhUMNI8KHfqhClEQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2Nd5jZN1vyk0C0rJaRzgvX)

[How to use MITMPROXY](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://blog.heckel.xyz/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/&ved=2ahUKEwiNgp-b8ePZAhUlSo8KHa8ACSIQFjAKegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3mjzb4n-Db4yOeLVIwlBHV)

Edit: If you are seeing this problem for 'only' `http` connection too, check the Network settings for your bridge adapter in VirtualBox.You should set `Promiscuous Mode` to `Allow All`.

Comment: Check SSLstrip too, long time I used it.If it works, you will not need mitmproxy.

Comment: This doesn't solve the specific problem, as the OP tested plain HTTP sites as well in the comments. We still don't know if OP can see any traffic at all either.